# Best way to float images in Bootstrap with margin and responsiveness?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and wondering what the best way to float images in Twitter Bootstrap 3 is. I have an image that can either be floated left or right of text content, but on a very small screen (ie. mobile) I want it to take up the full width. I also want some margin between image and content which I have had to add inline.

So far I have code something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="sample 1" class="img-thumbnail pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="/resource/image/35392/1.jpg?w=110" />
    </a>
    <p>Test of main image and gallery...</p>
</div>
```

This ends up looking something like this:

[image]

This looks okay but doesn't meet my need for taking full width on a very small screen.

Note that I would like the text to flow around (including under) the image too, rather than it just being a column. Hopefully this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Split the text image and text to its right into columns.

http://jsfiddle.net/Er5gV/

Add this CSS: img {width: 100%;}

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placeimg.com/200/260/tech" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other way is to use a float and then control it with a media query.

http://jsfiddle.net/2pGew/

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placeimg.com/200/260/tech" alt=""/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Magna sed cillum occaecat exercitation do ad consectetur ut qui mollit pariatur irure veniam cillum ut reprehenderit consectetur amet reprehenderit elit incididunt enim tempor proident magna dolore amet occaecat enim proident dolor magna eu.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your second example. I thought Bootstrap might have already had something to do this.